# Customize existing function in R

Tags: r, custom-function, psych

I want to change a condition within the function `psych::polychoric` in R.
Specifically, I want to increase the limit of different realizations of a a variable from 8 to 10 on line 77 of the code.
I can manually increase the limit by calling

```
trace(polychoric, edit=TRUE)
```

Since the script is meant for reproduction purposes for a paper of mine, I want to make handling as smooth as possible by avoiding manual editing.
Is there a way to edit the function by a piece code,
e.g. by replacing `if (nvalues > 8)` by `if (nvalues > 10)` in the code by another function?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find the location in the function that you want to change

```
as.list(body(psych::polychoric))
```

Change the function

```
trace(psych::polychoric, quote(nvalues > 10), at=11)
```

Check to see that you changed what you want to change

```
trace(psych::polychoric, edit=TRUE)
```

Set the function back to original

```
untrace(psych::polychoric)
```

## -----

Seems like `fix` may be easier for you to implement for this task

```
fix(polychoric)
```

opens a pane that you can change the code in - change and hit save.

This will make the function local to your global environment you can check this by looking at the original function `trace(polychoric, edit = T)` will show `nvalues > 10`, and `trace(psych::polychoric, edit = T)` will show `nvalues > 8`. The next time you reload `psych` you will be using the original function. Bit of a manual hack - but hopefully works for this one off situation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive help!
I have tried this approach before, but I was always using a string as a parameter for quote(). 
I've got a `.doTrace()` call in the code now.

Comment: Sry to bother you again, but I cannot get this to work. I called `trace(psych::polychoric,tracer=quote(nvalues > 11), at=list(c(11, 4, 9, 2)))`, which resulted in
`if({
      .doTrace("nvalues > 11 &", "step 11,4,9,2")
      nvalues > 8
    })`
on line 77.
However, when calling `polychoric()` I receive the usual error message,

_Error in polychoric(dta.y, smooth = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE, correct = FALSE) : 
  You have more than 8 categories for your items, polychoric is probably not needed_

Comment: Sounds like you may be better off using `fix` I added an edit to the bottom of my original post

Comment: `trace(polychoric, edit=T)` just works fine aswell. I can even call `untrace(polychoric)` afterwards to undo the changes. I just do not want for my reviewer to change the function parameter manually in an editor. But I guess a verbose instruction will have to do it.
Thank you very much for your effort and help. I very much appreciate it.